# godot game instances positions

Tags: godot, godot4

I'm making a multiplayer game and I'm running 2 instances of the game and I want that when starting from the editor, the windows of these instances appear side by side from each other (one on the floor of the screen on the left, the other on the floor of the screen on the right).

I know that you can adjust the position of the game window in the editor, but how to do it for 2 instances?